# What kind of information is shown on airport surface traffic surveillance displays?

Tags: air-traffic-control

[image]What kind of information is displayed by the ground surveillance radar scope on Advanced Surface Movement Guidance and Control Systems (A-SMGCS) or similar systems like [ASDE-X](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/technology/asde-x/)?

Comment: ground surveillance= aircraft+vehicles the display that shows the information about who's moving in the ground.

Comment: I think he's asking about the display the controller sees with an ASDE-X scope or something similar, and I think that's a great question (if that doesn't get outside of scope -- no pun intended).

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12327/what-data-is-displayed-on-civilian-atc-radar-screens)

Comment: @RalphJ Exactly, that's why it's related: this is the ground-based equivalent of the other question. I think for anyone interested in what ATC (including ground control) can see on their screens, it's good to make that link

Comment: first I'm a she :p and second thank you for editing my question because I'm new to this and find it hard to express what I need to know. thx again

Comment: Just to confirm: You want a detailed explanation of what each table and icon/Datatag on that screen is showing? I have not worked with ASDE-X before, but the screenshot awfully looks like a representation of simulated traffic from a flight simulator?

Comment: yes that's what I need to know !

Comment: @LazyBrain Would an explanation of the screenshot suffice or are you looking for a real ASDE-X screen (which I would have to hunt down).?

Comment: I would be thankful for a real ASDE-X one !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Advanced Surface Movement Guidance and Control System (A-SMGCS) provides controllers (eventually pilots and  vehicle  drivers)  with  situational 
awareness on the movement area and  normally  consists of three type of sensors. Surface movement radar, MLAT and ADS-B. 
[image: ASMGS Components]

The kind of information is displayed to the controller is dependent on what are the sensors used and the capability of aircraft and vehicles on the ground.

1. If the A-SMGCS is equipped with Surface Movement Radar (SMR) it can display the moving vehicles and aircraft on the maneuvering area. (except in areas where tracking is inhibited ) to the controller. But manual correlation is required to identify the target.
2. If ASMGCS is ADS-B capable, controllers display will show Aircraft or vehicle  Identification (ACID), Essential Flight Plan details like destination etc and type of aircraft also in addition to the exact location of the aircrat or vehicle. For this to work, Aircraft/vehicle should be ADS-B capable.
3. using  MLAT (Multilateration ) ASMGCS system displays postion and ACID and other FPL details to the controller if the aircraft SSR transponder is in operating mode. System correlate the transponder code with the flightplan.

[image: SMR Radar track]

Depending upon the level of ASMGCS operation , it can also display the taxiway route, SID, Runway assigned etc to the controller.

If the target is obtained from ADS-B or MLAT then it is called a cooperative sensor target. It will be displayed in a different symbol.