# How does ATC radar display differ from military radar?

Tags: air-traffic-control, military, radar

Could you summarize what sort of data/objects are present in one type of display but not another? (not asking about construction differences, just the user-facing end, the display/interface.)

A somewhat related question ["What data is displayed on civilian ATC radar screens?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12327/what-data-is-displayed-on-civilian-atc-radar-screens) shows example ATC displays. What of these would military radars miss (like obviously unknown data about enemy aircraft) and what extra would they present? Also - what sort of objects would appear on one but not another (in particular: non-aircraft; I heard for example flocks of birds sometimes appear on the radar, but never what kind of radar.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=-IX_WvK7OoL8jwPoy5WoCw&q=stars+radar+display&oq=stars+radar&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0l2j0i22i30k1l4j0i22i10i30k1l2j0i22i30k1l2.342.6106.0.8364.20.17.2.0.0.0.250.2180.0j13j1.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.15.2053.0..0i131k1j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i13i5i10i30k1j0i8i13i10i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.yk-iUW43xmY)

has numerous depictions of Raytheon made STARS (Standard Terminal Automation Replacement System)

Wikipedia says

> The system is currently being used at a number of TRACON sites throughout the US[2](https://www.raytheon.com/capabilities/products/stars_dod) and a number of military RAPCON sites that control military air traffic.[3]
>
> The STARS is part of the FAA's TAMR project to replace aging hardware and software at TRACONS. It is also called TAMR Phase I.[4] The larger TRACONs still use Common ARTs capable equipment but the FAA announced in Spring 2011 that TAMR Segment 3 Phase 1 will consist of replacing these 11 larger TRACONS with STARS by 2016. Simultaneously, all Terminal areas in the United States will phase out all CARTS and ARTS systems and switch to STARS. The smaller sites will transitions to the STARS ELITE (Enhanced Local Integrated Tower Equipment) version of software and hardware, which is similar to TAMR, but with minimum redundancy. The FAA plans to complete this process by 2020.

So it would seem that in many locations there would be [no difference](https://www.raytheon.com/capabilities/products/stars_dod).

> Raytheon's DoD STARS, also known as DoD Advanced Automated Systems (DAAS), provides a state-of-the-art air traffic control system for managing terminal area airspace for the US military.
>
> DoD STARS includes 191 RAPCON facilities with 59 associated towers and 21 stand-alone towers.
>
> STARS receives radar data and flight plan information and presents the information to air traffic controllers on high resolution, 20" x 20" color displays allowing the controller to monitor, control, and accept hand-off of air traffic.
>
> The Terminal Controller Workstations (TCW) provide position-by-position in-place replacement of failing existing system displays. They provide up to 14 adaptable data block types and 16 adaptable list types to accommodate current and future display requirements. The TCW also provides controllers with preference sets that allow for ease in shift changes and re-sectorization.
>
> The color displays are specially developed for air traffic control and are capable of displaying six distinct levels of weather data (identified by different colors) simultaneously with air traffic, allowing controllers to direct aircraft around bad weather.
>
> The color displays are specially developed for air traffic control and are capable of displaying six distinct levels of weather data (identified by different colors) simultaneously with air traffic, allowing controllers to direct aircraft around bad weather.
>
> STARS is capable of tracking up to 1350 airborne aircraft simultaneously within a terminal area. The system interfaces with multiple radars (up to 16 short and long range), 128 controller positions, 20 remote towers, and a 400 by 400 mile area of coverage.
>
> STARS has two separate, fully redundant automation systems running in parallel providing an instantaneous back-up service to controllers. The Full Service Level (FSL) is based on Raytheon's AutoTrac air traffic management system and the Emergency Service Level (ESL) is based on Raytheon's TracView automation product.